# Li with float in IE6/7. It disappears?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css-float

Try test this code in IE 6/7:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li style="float:left">huisashaiuhs iuhuiahsiuhsaiu</li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Where is the circle of LI? I already do ALL types of workaround, in UL and LI. Nothing, NOTHING works.

Do you have any idea? (BTW already tried hasLayout,padding-left,margin-left,display:inline, etc etc etc)

Answer (score 0):

Check this forum article out: http://www.highdots.com/forums/alt-html/float-li-bullets-ie7-277086.html

Or else, I'd suggest putting the `<ul>` in a `<div>` that is floated left, and remove the float style from the `<li>`.

e.g.

```
  <div style="float: left;">
    <ul>
      <li>huisashaiuhs iuhuiahsiuhsaiu</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: TO do the behavior that i want, i need to style each LI of UL, so your solution wont works... =/

Comment: Okay, another option would be to display a small image before your text to take the place of the bullet point.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a doctype to kick the page into standards mode?